# twitter bootstrap with jquery input token SASS version not working correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I'm trying to use the [twitter bootstrap sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) version with [jQuery input token](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) in Ruby on Rails. I found the [jQuery tokenInput bootstrap sass theme](https://github.com/dbraga/jquery-tokeninput-bootstrap-sass-theme), and have added it as it says in the documentation.

Problem is that when it is displayed it doesn't look very good. It's missing all kinds of small UI things like backgrounds and such.

**What I see:**

No background to dropdown list:

[image]

Bad styling for chosen tokens:

[image]

No styling for input box...

[image]

The [less version](https://github.com/dkharrat/jquery-tokeninput-bootstrap-theme) looks like it should look normal. Is there something wrong with the scss version? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the last update to the SASS version was 1 year ago, so i need to update it to the new version.
I'll work on it this few days and i'll close the issue